# Como atribuir efeitos de clique em um ImageButton?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Por exemplo,
Adicionei ao meu layout xml uma ImageButton, coloquei uma imagem e deixei com background transparente, por ter feito isso ele perdeu as características de um botão, como faço para adicionar efeito de clique?

Comment: Tente reformular essa questão por início meio e fim e não simplesmente "mandar", seja específico, cordial e técnico.

Comment: ficou melhor? @user3163662

Comment: Ainda não consigo entender o que você está tentando fazer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa criar um drawable para ele, informando quais as cores para os respectivos estados. Para isto, crie um arquivo .xml dentro da pasta `drawable`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/sua_cor_selecionado" />
            <padding android:bottom="3dp" android:left="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:top="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <padding android:bottom="3dp" android:left="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:top="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_enabled="false">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <padding android:bottom="3dp" android:left="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:top="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <padding android:bottom="3dp" android:left="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:top="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

E, após criar, atribua em seu `ImageButton`:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/seu_botao"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/seu_arquivo_criado"/>
```